# How do I pass PHP variables through jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Okay so I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/screen-resolution-notequalto-browser-window/) but instead of storing it in a database I'm gonna store it somewhere else.

One problem though I have no clue how to append PHP variables with jQuery to the body!

Here is index.php

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Store Your Browser Resolution!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn-POST">CLICK</button>
</body>
```

Here is Main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn-POST").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/index.php',
    data: {
        width        : $(window).width(),
        height       : $(window).height(),
        screen_width : screen.width,
        screen_height: screen.height
    },
    success: function( data )
    {
        console.log('SUCCESS!');
        $("body").append($('<?php $width = $_POST["width"]; $height = $_POST["height"]; $screen_width = $_POST["screen_width"]; $screen_height = $_POST["screen_height"]; ?>'));
        $("body").delay(800).append($('<?php echo  ?>'))
    }
    }); 
});
console.log('Test!');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

-Alex

Comment: `index.php` should insert the POST variables into the result that it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the user has loaded the `HTML` / `PHP` site from your server it's **impossible** to execute more `PHP` commands.

This is because `PHP` is server sided, the user requests the document, your server executes all php commands and give the user the resulting HTML document.

Adding `PHP` code via JavaScript is *clientside*, so it won't work.

Comment: So what could I do to, echo this data on my index.php page?

Comment: @abrad1212 That's exactly what you should do.

Comment: @abrad1212 simply add the data to your `body` or content. (Maybe in a div / span) e.g. `$("body").append(data);`

Comment: **Thank YOU SO MUCH :)**

Comment: Actually how would I go about doing _Width: then the width_ _Height: then the height_ Cause it looks like 600
775
1600
900

Comment: @abrad1212 i need more information about your result and what you want to do

Comment: Goto http://abrad1212.xyz/Experimental/Store%20Resolution/  and click on the button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115237/discussion-between-sese-schneider-and-abrad1212).

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to use php in your javascript file, but you could always declare you javascript variable in your `index.php` file and call those javascript objects in your javascript file.
ex:

```
//index.php
<script>
    var width = '<?php echo $_POST["width"]; ?>';
    ....
<script>
```

now just call the variables in your javascript file.

```
//Main.js
$("body").append(width+....);
```